# "Invalid Datetime" for JSON when uploading to GCP BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get some records into BigQuery, but I've gotten stuck at a date error. I've tried formatting the date in the way that BQ want, but these haven't seemed to help. Here is a (fake, obviously) record I am trying to work with.

```
{"ID":"1","lastName":"Doe","firstName":"John","middleName":"C","DOB":"1901-01-01 00:00:00","gender":"Male","MRN":"1","diagnosis":["something"],"phone":"888-555-5555","fax":"888-555-5555","email":"j@doe.org"}
```

And here is the error that I get when I try and upload the file

```
Provided Schema does not match Table x:y.z. Field dob has changed type from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP
```

I'm just not sure what the difference in my format could be that BQ is unhappy about. I have my date formatted properly, the time is formatted properly (even tried `00:00:00.0`), but I just can't seem to get this data into the table. I've also not specified any time zone, which makes it even odder that it thinks I'm supplying a timestamp.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what if you remove `00:00:00` to make it `1901-01-01`?

Comment: @Thanks for the input Felipe. I have actually tried that as well, but the error becomes
`Field dob has changed type from DATETIME to DATE`, so that doesn't work either. I think I'll contact the administrator and see if we can just switch the column type to either DATE or TIMESTAMP. It's just so odd that it won't accept the structure that is DATETIME as far as I can tell

Comment: Oh you're right. I guess for the current auto-detection for JSON fields `TIMESTAMP` would be a better fit than `DATETIME`

Comment: I just tried replicating your scenario via BigQuery UI and CLI commands while [loading JSON to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_json_data_into_a_new_table) and [appending a table with JSON data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_json_data) by using `DATETIME` as the "DOB" data type and I didn't have any issues. Even with `--autodetect` works well (But it uses `TIMESTAMP` instead). Can you provide more info on how you're trying to load your JSON data?